# How to customize a spinner?

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

I would like to customize a spinner so that it wraps around a box, like the model below.
The image is not very good, but you can get an idea of how it should look.
Does anyone know how I can do it? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7vy3.png)

Comment: does this answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48503427/custom-spinner-android

Comment: Did my answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a `drawable` with a `solid` and `stroke` to make a box around it. Then you set the `drawable` as `background` of the `Spinner`. Here `android:background="@drawable/background"`.

**background.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="1"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#2962FF" />
    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="#AEEA00" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp" />
</shape>
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2962FF">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Result:**

[image]